# arabic data is not displaying in ie8

Tags: html, ajax, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am facing a problem with Arabic data. It is not displaying properly in **IE** whereas it is displaying properly in **Chrome**.

I am using two files 'frameset.html'& 'legend.html' . 'legend.html' has Arabic content.Earlier I used div's in place of frames in 'frameset.html' and the Arabic data was working fine but after I changed, it is having problem.

Frameset.html:

```
 <html>

 <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

     <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

$("#topArb").load("Top_arb.jsp");
$("#actionBar").load("ActionBar.jsp");
$("#viewInbox").load("ViewInbox.jsp");
$("#legend").load("Legend.html");
$("#nav").load("Nav.jsp");

  });

   </script>

      </head>

      <body>
      <div id="main-container">

      <div id="topArb">
      </div>
       <div id="left-container">
   <div id="actionBar">
    </div>

     <div id="viewInbox">
  </div>
     <div id="legend">
     </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right-container">
     <div id="nav">
    </div>
   </div>
   </body>
  </HTML>
```

legend.html:-

```
     <HTML >
        <HEAD>
          <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


      </HEAD>

   <BODY topmargin=0>
<table align="center" style="" width="100%" height="20">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/newH.gif" WIDTH="16"     HEIGHT="16"
                        BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">وثيقة عاجلة</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/new.gif" WIDTH="16"  HEIGHT="16" BORDER="0"
                        ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">وثيقة عادية</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/BnewH.gif" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16"
                        BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">وثيقة مؤرشفة عاجلة</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/Bnew.gif" WIDTH="16" HEIGHT="16"
                        BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">وثيقة مؤرشفة عادية</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/CloseDoc.gif" WIDTH="18" HEIGHT="18"
                        BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">غير مقروء</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/OpenDoc.gif" WIDTH="18" HEIGHT="18"
                        BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">مقروء</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/L.gif" WIDTH="18" HEIGHT="18" BORDER="0"
                        ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">رد</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC="imgs/ic_waitingreply.gif" WIDTH="18"
                        HEIGHT="18" BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">نسخة من الوثيقة</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>

            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC='images/ic_suspend.gif' WIDTH="18" HEIGHT="18"
                        BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">الأعمال المؤجلة</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><IMG SRC='imgs/ic_close.gif' WIDTH="18" HEIGHT="18"
                        BORDER="0" ALT=""></td>
                    <td class="SET">الأعمال المغلقة</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>

        <td><IMG SRC="imgs/Drafts.gif" WIDTH="18" HEIGHT="18" BORDER="0"
            ALT=""></td>
        <td class="SET">مسودة</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
    </BODY>
```

Here my legend.html(marked) is displayed in junk data instead of arabic data
[image]

Comment: Try to specify a doctype by adding `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the beginning of the HTML document.

Comment: @vagga, Which version of IE are you using. This code worked fine for me in IE10 and chrome.

Comment: Like @PavloMykhalov said, add the Doctype. As a sidenote, please refrain from using tables to style elements. It's an old technique that's been left behind since HTML4 and 5. Unless ofcourse you want whatever it is you've made to be in a table, in that case nevermind :P.

Comment: It would be better if you put an external link to see the origin of problem.

Comment: @PavloMykhalov i tried with doctype also but there is no use

Comment: @AnaMaria i am using IE 8

Comment: This code work for me on IE8

Comment: Make a screenshoot to see what type of problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

If the document gets corrupted only when loaded via AJAX, try `ajaxSetup()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  "beforeSend": function (xhr) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
  }
});

$("#legend").load("Legend.html");
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.I tried with the above code but there is no use

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved just by changing the file from legend.html to legend.jsp